# How to connect and send data to intel edison using wi-fi from android device

Tags: android, intel-edison

I want make connection with intel edison using wifi from android phone, and send data to intel edison.

I am new to this so, pleas help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what did you try so far ? any code we can view and help you with ?

Comment: actually i want to connect my android phone to intel edison via wi-fi. intel edison is connect with my wifi network. I want to send text data to intel edison from android phone. i have no code currently i am just finding. @MurtazaKhursheedHussain

Comment: then you are in a wrong place. SO is to help when you are stuck. hopefully you will find what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Wifi Direct and set up a static ip address so that you can use your Android device to connect to the Intel Edison anywhere, regardless of whether there is a network in the area. Think of it as a substitute for Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can connect android device to intel Edison using wi-fi connection.

connect both device in same network, and get ip address of intel edison.

First we need to open port to listening, mean open serversocket in intel edison, then implement clientsocket in androd device.

now connect clientsocket to serversocket, with intel edison ip and port.
now you can send data android phone to intel edison or visa versa.